# How to apply a 'moving window' to analyse chunks of text sequentially in Python?

Tags: python, text

I would like to calculate the simple moving window average type/ token ratio (TTR) of a text sample. I know how to calculate the TTR of the whole text, or to select the first 50 words and calculate the TTR for that. What I think I need to do is create a loop that iterates over 50 words at a time, with the start moving +1 each time so the window moves through the text, appending the resulting TTR for each window in to a list that I can then average. It's the looping/ chunking/ +1 part I'm stuck on.

This is what I (think) I want to do in the loop. Text has already been lowered etc.:

```
window = text[0:50]
wordCount = collections.Counter(window)
uniqueWords = list(wordCount.keys())
TTR = (len(uniqueWords))/(len(window)) 
windowsTTR.append(TTR)
```

I have read other answers here, as well as documentation for enumerate and itertools.islice, but still can't seem to solve my problem. Any help gratefully receieved, I'm fairly new to Python.

Comment: When you get the answer you needed here on SO you should, please, mark it 'accepted'. When you have sufficient reputation you can up-vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parametrize your loop body according to a start position.  Then iterate through all possible start positions.

```
window_width = 50
last_index = len(text) - window_width
for start in range (last_index):
    window = text[start:start+window_width]
    wordCount = collections.Counter(window)
    uniqueWords = list(wordCount.keys())
    TTR = (len(uniqueWords))/(len(window)) 
    windowsTTR.append(TTR)
```

If you need to take larger steps through the text, then parametrize that, as well:

```
window_width = 50
last_index = len(text) - window_width
step = 4    # shift 4 positions at a time
for start in range (0, last_index, step):
```